# qzxing on ios not recognizing qr codes (only barcodes)

Tags: ios, qr-code, barcode, zxing

I've successfully run the QZXingLive example on ios 10.2 (iphone 5c), I've also added the nscamerausagedescription tag in info.plist to access the camera.
The problem is that it's not able to recognize qr codes, it reads only barcodes, are there limitations on this platform?
On Windows 7 and Android I don't have such problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the ios acquired camera data that was flipped and rotated.
The mantainer of qzxing made a fix for this problem:
https://github.com/ftylitak/qzxing/issues/32